# C# How to sort all columns of worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, sorting

I have only come across examples where you sort 3 columns, and cannot figure out how (or even if its possible) to sort by all columns from first column to last.

I have the below code for sorting by 3 specific columns:

```
//Sort the range based on 1st, 3rd, and 8th
oRng.Sort(oRng.Columns[1, Type.Missing], Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
oRng.Columns[3, Type.Missing], Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
oRng.Columns[8, Type.Missing], Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlGuess, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns, Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin,
Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal,
Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal,
Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal);
```

My worksheet has 10 columns, so how would I go about sorting by all?

I tried also the below code but it only seems to sort by the first column

```
Excel.Range tempRange = clsWorksheet.UsedRange;
oRng.Sort(tempRange,
Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
Type.Missing,
Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlGuess,
Type.Missing,
Type.Missing,
Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns,
Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin,
Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal,
Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal,
Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal);
```

Comment: Not sure which excel version you are using, but it's worth to take a look on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10223917/1050927)

Comment: I'm using Excel 2016. I have seen that but I don't know how to convert it to c#.

Comment: Also I should mention that the number of columns is not necessarily 10 like I mention above. It's never fixed but I mentioned 10 just for the sake of including a number higher than 3 which seems like the maximum Excel.Range.Sort accepts. The solution in that post assumes you have 5 columns, but again it will vary.

Comment: I don't have the proper environment to test it.  But if you can't work out with that, maybe you can use the old way to do multiple sort: [Link](https://superuser.com/a/75701/756913)

Comment: What is the old way?

Comment: Have you check the link? _by sorting 1 column at a time, in the reverse order_.  However, you cannot tell the data are sort by which column in excel.